# Is there a limit to update the global variable? google app script to telegram bot

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram-bot

currently my code is able to run till currentstep = '2'. I have updated the currentstep = '3' in my survey(data) which will be able to execute my xD(data). However, the code isn't updated to '3' to run.

```
function check_command(data){
  var text = data.message.text;
  
  if(text == "/start" || text == "/start"){
    currentstep = '1';
    return;
  }
  
  if (text == "/survey" || text == "/survey"){
    currentstep = '2';
    return;
  }
 
  return;
}  


function process_loop(data){

  if(currentstep == "1"){
    start(data);
    return;
  }
  
  if(currentstep == "2"){
    survey(data);
    return;
  }
  
  if(currentstep == "3"){
    xD(data);
    return;
  }
}

function doPost(e){
  
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  
  check_command(data);
  process_loop(data); 
  
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve].  Please note it say that the example you provide must allow us to reproduce the  problem.  It doesn't have to be your actual code.  It's an example to help us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, You mentioned that you are setting `currentstep = '3'` in your `survey(data)`.

Whenever you receive a doPost(), you will set `currentstep` to either 1 or 2 in `check_command(data)`. Then it will call `process_loop(data)`. If the  currentstep is initially 2, it will be set to 3 in `survey(data)`. However, since you include `return` statement, it will exit the `process_loop(data)`. Hence `xD(data)` will not be executed.

You can decide whether remove the `return` statement in `(currentstep == "2")` only or to remove them in each condition.